# Changing JButton text from another class with a value of Int

Tags: java, getter-setter

will be glad if you can help me along. By right I have 2 classes. The first one is the UI(GameJPanel) class where I declared all my private buttons etc.. The second class is the gameEngine(GameMechanismPlayer)  that generate values to be set on the JButton"textFields". The generated value from the gameEngine are Integers. I'm trying to, from the second Class change the the Button Text but i'm getting error. I belive that I should be using getters and setters from the UI Class. Can you please help me..

```
public class GameJPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JToggleButton die1, 
    private JButton rollDice;

    public GameJPanel()
    {
        //Dice Toggle Buttons       
        die1 = new JToggleButton("Die 1");
        die1.setBounds(300,350,70,25);
        add(die1);
        //Roll Dice
        rollDice = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rollDice.setBounds(400,400,270,50);
        add(rollDice);

        rollDice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                playGame.play();
            }       
        });
        setVisible(true); 
        setLayout(null);
        }

    public JToggleButton getDie1()
    {
        return die1;
    }

    public void setDie1(JToggleButton die1)
    {
        this.die1 = die1;
    }
}


public class GameMechanismPlayer
{
    private int[] randomDiceArrayNumber;
    private int dieIndexPosition;
    private Random randomDice;
    private boolean isPlayerOneTurn = true;
    GameJPanel uI = new GameJPanel();

    public GameMechanismPlayer()
    {
        play();     
    }

    public void play()
    {

        for(turn = 0 ; turn <= 3 || scoreSelected == true; turn++)
        {
            randomDice = new Random(); 
            randomDiceArrayNumber = new int [5];

            for(dieIndexPosition = 0; dieIndexPosition < randomDiceArrayNumber.length; dieIndexPosition++)
            {
                randomDiceArrayNumber[dieIndexPosition] = 1+randomDice.nextInt(6);
            }
            sumsMutipleByItsOwnNumber();

            if(isPlayerOneTurn = true)
            {
                //Here it is not working
                uI.setDie1(String.valueof(randomDiceArrayNumber[0]))
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible types!

1. Your definition:

   ```
   // this expects an argument of type JToggleButton
   public void setDie1(JToggleButton die1) {
       this.die1 = die1;
   }
   ```
2. Your calling statement:

   ```
   uI.setDie1(String.valueof(randomDiceArrayNumber[0])); // this is trying to pass a String to the method setDie1
   ```
3. Instead, something like this(just correcting the syntax) should work:

   ```
   uI.setDie1(new JToggleButton(String.valueof(randomDiceArrayNumber[0])));
   ```